# Response in RAX-RS

Tags: multithreading, rest, jax-rs

I am writing exercise using Restful in Java. I give a rangle IP, each IP is processed by one thread (do something). Now i wanna when a thread complete it will return to browser result. And when all thread complete, all result will appear on browser. How can do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look into the [`ManagedExecutorSerivce`](https://concurrency-ee-spec.java.net/javadoc/javax/enterprise/concurrent/ManagedExecutorService.html) for concurrent processing and the [`AsyncResponse`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/AsyncResponse.html) in combination with the `@Suspended` annotation for the request handling.